# if $s=\sqrt{x^2+6x+9} +\sqrt{x^2+24x+144}$ and $-10 < x < -8$ there follows that...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> if $s=\sqrt{x^2+6x+9} + \sqrt{x^2+24x+144}$ and $-10 < x < -8$ there follows that $s=9$

After noticing that the first radical is $x+3$ and the second one is  $x+12$ all I get is $s=2x+15$, which btw. is suggested as an alternative answer in the exam.
So, how to go about this?

Comment: Is $x$ an integer?

Comment: The first radical is $|x+3|$ and the second radical is $|x+12|$, so the LHS is the sum of the distances of $x$ from $-12$ and $-3$. For any $x$ in the interval $[-12,-3]\supset(-10,-8)$ this sum is constant and it equals the length of $[-12,-3]$, i.e. $9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $\sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 9} = \sqrt{(x + 3)^2} = x + 3$ since $x + 3 < 0$ if $x < -3$.  Remember that $\sqrt{x}$ is the [principal (nonnegative) square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) of $x$.    Actually,
$$\sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 9} = |x + 3|$$
Similarly,
$$\sqrt{x^2 + 24x + 144} = |x + 12|$$
Since $x + 3 \geq 0$ if $x \geq -3$ and $x + 3 < 0$ if $x < -3$,
$$
|x + 3| = \begin{cases}
x + 3 & \text{if $x \geq -3$}\\
-x - 3 & \text{if $x < -3$}
\end{cases}
$$ 
Since $x + 12 \geq 0$ if $x \geq -12$ and $x + 12 < 0$ if $x < -12$
$$
|x + 12| = \begin{cases}
x + 12 & \text{if $x \geq -12$}\\
-x - 12 & \text{if $x < -12$}
\end{cases}
$$ 
Thus, if $-10 < x < -8$,
\begin{align*}
s & = \sqrt{x^2 + 6x + 9} + \sqrt{x^2 + 12x + 24}\\
  & = |x + 3| + |x + 12|\\
  & = -x - 3 + x + 12\\
  & = 9 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$x^2+6x+9=(x+3)^2$$ and $$x^2+24x+144=(x+12)^2$$, so you will get
$$s=|x+3|+|x+12|$$, now consider the inequality $$-10<x<-8$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{x^2+6x+9} = \pm(x+3)$$

And

$$\sqrt{x^2+24x+144} = \pm(x+12)$$

Hence $$S = \pm (x+3) \pm (x+12)$$

There are $4$ different cases :

$$S = 2x+15$$
$$S = -9$$
$$S = 9$$
And 
$$S = -2x-15$$

Comment: What does it mean $\sqrt{x^2+6x+9}=\pm(x+3)$? The square root is a function and $\sqrt{x^2+6x+9}$ equals $|x+3|$.